# OrientDB: how to set timezone to Europe/Rome

Tags: sql, timezone, orientdb

I'm using OrientDB community edition 2.1.11 on a Ubuntu 14.04 server.

I used

```
ALTER DATABASE TIMEZONE UTC
```

to change the timezone because I had some problem with Daylight Savings Time (DST). Since this change caused me several big problems with some other scripts I would like to set the timezone back to "Europe/Rome".

I tried

```
ALTER DATABASE TIMEZONE "Europe/Rome"
```

and

```
ALTER DATABASE TIMEZONE Europe/Rome
```

from Studio, but both these commands set the timezone to GMT. I also tried

```
ALTER DATABASE TIMEZONE GMT+1
```

and this works as expected setting the timezone to GMT+01:00.
This will be a problem this weekend when we will go from GMT+1 (CET) to GMT+2 (CEST, summer time), while I guess that "Europe/Rome" would correctly change from CET to CEST.

Could you please tell me what is the correct syntax to go back to "Europe/Rome" timezone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please open an issue for the command `ALTER DATABASE TIMEZONE "Europe/Rome"`?